# Redirect all requests to main page using htaccess (hide index.html in URL)

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to redirect all requests to main page (index.html). URL in status bar should not show index.html. At this moment I'm using the following code which redirects to index.html and shows it in URL:

`RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(gif|jpeg|png|css|js)$
    RewriteRule .* /index.html [L,R=302]`

What changes I should make to make it work as I intend? Thanks!

Comment: Should be working without `R=302` flag. Only use `[L]` flag (internal rewrite)

Comment: It doesn't work. Actually it doesn't redirect at all.

Comment: Than you made a mistake somewhere else. Remove R=302 (and comma in front of it), this causes redirect headers sent to the browser. If everything is working - it will work even better without that flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index.html)?$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(gif|jpeg|png|css|js)$ 
RewriteRule .* / [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 1):

If it works as intended, except of the external redirect of the browser, then you need just to remove R=302 flag, which tells server to send 302 headers.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(gif|jpeg|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L]
```

And check also `DirectoryIndex` directive, to show index.html by default (if it was changed)